# How can I present Menu (Not context menu) by using a Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
var body: some View {
     Menu("Actions") {
         Button("Duplicate", action: duplicate)
         Button("Rename", action: rename)
         Button("Delete…", action: delete)
       }
   }
}

Button(action:{ 
   MainMenuView()                   
}, label: { Text("More") })
```

I have a "Menu" view it's just a menu, and I want to present it in another view using button action closure, so when tapping the button the menu pops up, anyone can help me with this, please.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this Using toolbar as an example**

```
.toolbar{
       ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
            Menu {
                Button(action: {//action}) {
                    Label("Bttn 1", systemImage: "text.badge.plus")
                }
                Button(action: {//action}) {
                    Label("Bttn 2", systemImage: "text.badge.plus")
                }
            }
            label: {
                Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That not work because I want the button inside the toolbar item present the menu view.

Comment: Can you explain I'm not sure I understand ?

Comment: I want to create a button inside toolbar item and that button present the Menu, and I don't want to put the menu directly in the toolbar item